# How to pass a props from parent to child css properties?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have a parent and child component there is a button in parent component on Clicking that button it should send a Props -"red" so the child should receive the red and change its background color as red. Below my code is there

[jsfiddle.net/t1ru6oyz/3/](http://jsfiddle.net/t1ru6oyz/3/)

**Child**

```
import React from "react";
import ReactDOM from "react-dom";

const childContainer = {
  border: "0px solid #000",
  width: "300px",
  height: "300px",
  textAlign: "middle",
  margin: "0 auto",
  marginTop: "60px"
};

const Child = props => {
  return (
    <div
      style={{
        backgroundColor: props.color
      }}
    />
  );
};

export default Child;
```

**Parent**

```
import React, { Component } from "react";
import "./App.css";
import Child from "./child";

const parentContainer = {
  border: "10px solid #000",
  width: "500px",
  height: "500px",
  margin: "20px",
  textAlign: "middle"
};

class App extends Component {
  constructor() {
    super();
    this.state = {
      currentColor: "red"
    };
  }
  componentDidMount() {
    this.setState({
      currectColor: "green"
    });
  }
  changeColor = () => {
    this.setState({
      currectColor: "blue"
    });
  };
  render() {
    console.log("in render", this.state);

    return (
      <div style={parentContainer}>
        <button onClick={this.changeColor}>Blue</button>
        <p>{this.state.name}</p>
        <Child color={this.state.currentColor} />
      </div>
    );
  }
}

export default App;
```

Answer (score 1):

You have a few typos there in your parent component like `currectColor`, just fix those first. Then, you can add the `backgroundColor` property to your `childContainer` if there is prop by checking it.

```js
const parentContainer = {
  border: "10px solid #000",
  width: "500px",
  height: "500px",
  margin: "20px",
  textAlign: "middle"
};

class App extends React.Component {
  constructor() {
    super();
    this.state = {
      currentColor: "red"
    };
  }
  componentDidMount() {
    this.setState({
      currentColor: "green"
    });
  }
  changeColor = () => {
    this.setState({
      currentColor: "blue"
    });
  };
  
  render() {
    return (
      <div style={parentContainer}>
        <button onClick={this.changeColor}>Blue</button>
        <p>{this.state.name}</p>
        <Child color={this.state.currentColor} />
      </div>
    );
  }
}



const Child = props => {
  let childContainer = {
    border: "0px solid #000",
    width: "300px",
    height: "300px",
    textAlign: "middle",
    margin: "0 auto",
    marginTop: "60px"
  };
  if ( props.color ) {
    childContainer = { ...childContainer, backgroundColor: props.color }
  }
  return (
    <div
      style={childContainer}
    />
  );
};

ReactDOM.render(<App />, document.getElementById("root"));
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react-dom.min.js"></script>
<div id="root"></div>
```

Comment: Great catch. I didn’t notice that typo:)

Answer (score 0):

I have created my own components, but you can apply this logic.

```js
class Child extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
  }
  render() {
    return ( <
      h1 style = {
        {
          backgroundColor: this.props.color
        }
      } > hello < /h1>
    )
  }
}

class Parent extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      color: ''
    }
  }
  handleClick = () => {
    this.setState({
      color: 'red'
    })

  }

  render() {
    return ( <
      div >
      <
      Child color = {
        this.state.color
      }
      /> <
      button onClick = {
        this.handleClick
      } > change Child color < /button> < /
      div >
    )
  }
}

ReactDOM.render( <
  Parent / > ,
  document.getElementById("root")
);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react-dom.min.js"></script>
<div id="root"></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You need change in App component. Keep currentColor to blue and change it to red in changeColor function but you are doing it in reverse

Try with below code

```
const parentContainer = {
  border: "10px solid #000",
  width: "500px",
  height: "500px",
  margin: "20px",
  textAlign: "middle"
};

class App extends Component {
  constructor() {
    super();
    this.state = {
      currentColor: "blue"
    };
  }
  componentDidMount() {
    this.setState({
      currentColor: "green"
    });
  }
  changeColor = () => {
    this.setState({
      currentColor: "red"
    });
  };
  render() {
    console.log("in render", this.state);

    return (
      <div style={parentContainer}>
        <button onClick={this.changeColor}>Blue</button>
        <p>{this.state.name}</p>
        <Child color={this.state.currentColor} />
      </div>
    );
  }
}

export default App;
```